# How to create and use a terminal command with nest-commander?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, node-commander

So, I have this NestJS project, and for learning purposes I want to create a command with [nest-commander](https://nest-commander.jaymcdoniel.dev/docs/features/commander/) that would be executable on terminal (that way I could call a function from other services), also for learning purposes, whenever I call this command, it should call a function on a service file that get's a user from the database.

It would look like this :

```sh
> run myCommand -username UsernameString
```

Whenever that command is called from the terminal, I would call `getUser()` from `AnotherService` to find my user with that specific UsernameString.
I read the docs and couldn't figure much of it, so...

1. How do I call a command from terminal?
2. Is it possible to call the same command within the application?

Comment: Tutorial you linked with is quite straight forward, what is not working?  As for executing the command from within the app, yes - but you need to make the command in other file that can be included by both ci and application and call the same code treating @Command and application part just as user interfaces that prepares parameters given to them from different sources and executing same code in the end.

Comment: It uses `crun run` to run the command, but when I try using crun, it doesn't recognize the command!

Comment: the docs saids _For now, we'll just assume this application is installed globally under the `crun` name._

Comment: [Node JS:Understanding `bin` in `package.json`](https://www.monkwhocode.com/2020/04/node-jsunderstanding-bin-in-packagejson.html). 
Also, read the docs: https://nest-commander.jaymcdoniel.dev/docs/executing/local/

Comment: Thanks! But in this case `node ./dist/main [args] [options]` running this command wound't just run my app? (it just did, but I might be a bit stupid, sorry), like: `node ./dist/main sayHello` just run my app

Comment: Is this a mixed (read Server and CLI application) or just a CLI application? Does your `main` end up calling `CommandFactory` or `NestFactory`?

Answer (score 5):

So basically if we take this example:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Command, CommandFactory, CommandRunner, Option } from 'nest-commander';

interface BasicCommandOptions {
  string?: string;
  boolean?: boolean;
  number?: number;
}

@Command({ name: 'basic', description: 'A parameter parse' })
export class BasicCommand extends CommandRunner {
  async run(
    passedParam: string[],
    options?: BasicCommandOptions,
  ): Promise<void> {
    if (options?.number) {
      this.runWithNumber(passedParam, options.number);
    } else if (options?.string) {
      this.runWithString(passedParam, options.string);
    } else {
      this.runWithNone(passedParam);
    }
  }

  @Option({
    flags: '-n, --number [number]',
    description: 'A basic number parser',
  })
  parseNumber(val: string): number {
    return Number(val);
  }

  @Option({
    flags: '-s, --string [string]',
    description: 'A string return',
  })
  parseString(val: string): string {
    return val;
  }

  @Option({
    flags: '-b, --boolean [boolean]',
    description: 'A boolean parser',
  })
  parseBoolean(val: string): boolean {
    return JSON.parse(val);
  }

  runWithString(param: string[], option: string): void {
    console.log({ param, string: option });
  }

  runWithNumber(param: string[], option: number): void {
    console.log({ param, number: option });
  }

  runWithNone(param: string[]): void {
    console.log({ param });
  }
}

@Module({
  providers: [BasicCommand],
})
export class AppModule {}

async function bootstrap() {
  await CommandFactory.run(AppModule);
}

bootstrap();
```

You can run it using that method:

```
ts-node ./test.ts basic -s test-value -n 1234
```

First you call the name of the command then the params

Comment: I guess the `main.ts` starts the server and if I want to have an entry point for the command I have to make another Typescript file?

Comment: The entrypoint can be what you want. It needs to contains the 'AppModule' and you need to regoster the commands inside the 'providers' array.

Answer (score 1):

Consider your project's nature: a versatile CLI designed for seamless terminal use. It stands alone, responsive to calls. In case my answer here does not fit you well you can try my [Step by Step NestJs Commander](https://medium.com/@jihadkahil.93/nestjs-commander-tutorial-facbd8c018d4).

First you need to create a command class for example here **command-tutorial.ts**

```
import { CommandRunner, Command, Option } from 'nest-commander';

@Command({
 name: 'basic',
 arguments: '[task]',
 description: 'A parameter parse',
 })
export class CommandTutorial extends CommandRunner {
   constructor() {
   super();
 }

async run(
  passedParams: string[],
  options?: Record<string, any>,
 ): Promise<void> {
  console.log('CLI Params', passedParams);
  console.log('CLI Options', options);
   return Promise.resolve(undefined);
}
 @Option({
  flags: '-n, --number [number]',
  description: 'A basic number parser',
 })
 parseNumber(val: string): number {
   return Number(val);
}
}
```

then inside the app.module.ts import this command

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CommandTutorial } from './command-tutorial';
@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [CommandTutorial],
  })
export class AppModule {}
```

inside your main.ts you need to add the shebang on the top of you of your code and plus change the bootstrap function

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { CommandFactory } from 'nest-commander';

async function bootstrap() {
   await CommandFactory.run(AppModule, {
   logger: ['warn', 'error'],
  });
}
bootstrap();
```

for testing your app it is so easy just run the following command

> ts-node main.ts basic argument -n 1

and check the result inside your CMD

now to run it with a terminal prompt you need to update your package.json and add the bin script

```
"bin": {
"tutorial": "dist/main.js"
 }
```

**"tutorial" will be your command you can change it to whatever you want**

and run the following command chmod +x main.ts (MAC OS check it is alternative in Windows/Unix)

then inside your NodeJs Project or NestJs Project install this as module using

- npm i path-to-your-nest-command-cli-directory

if you would like to be globally inside your machine

- npm i g path-to-your-nest-command-cli-directory

Now run tutorial basic argument -n 1 inside your cmd or terminal you should get

CLI Params: argument
CLI Option: {n:1}

All the best